# JQuery button hide and making condition

Tags: jquery-validate

I want to hide a button until other button is getting submitted.

ex. button1 is hidden.
    button 2 visible
 if(button2 submitted)
    button 1 get visible.

can you tell a method to do that??

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather new to jQuery, but I believe this may work:

**HTML**:

```
<form id="someform">
...
</form>
```

**JS**:

```
$(function() {
  $('#button1').hide();
}

$('#someform').submit(function() {
  $('#button2').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#button1').bind('click', function() {
   $(this).hide();
   $('#button2).show();
});

$('#button2').bind('click, function() {
   $(this).hide(); 
   $('#button1).show()      
});
```